# Start or Stop services in multiple Windows EC2 Instances using AWS Systems Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have multiple EC2 instances in different accounts under the Organization, we have a requirement to stop a service in Windows, please guide the easiest built in service to perform this activity

I was able to do this by following this blog- https://cloudsolutionsonline.blogspot.com/2021/07/start-or-stop-services-in-multiple.html?m=1

Following the steps I achieved my use case

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Run command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), which is part of System Manager can be used to execute PowerShell (`Start-Service` | `Stop-Service`) commands on the instances. You can target multiple instances in the *same Org account* via instance tags or Instance Ids. I dont know of a way to do this across multiple org accounts that could be described as "easiest" or with "built in" tools. But...

A fairly easy option is to invoke Run command via PowerShell locally/on a server (you need to install the [AWS Powershell Tools](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) on this machine).

Below command will attempt to:

- stop a service named `NameOfMyService`
- Only on instances with a tag called `ROLE` and with a value of `WEBSERVER`
- using credential named `OrgAccountX` (ie created with `Set-AWSCredential` command) you need one profile per account.

```
$runPSCommand = Send-SSMCommand `
    -ProfileName OrgAccountX
    -Target "Key=tag:ROLE,Values=WEBSERVER" `
    -DocumentName "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" `
    -Parameter @{'commands'=@('Stop-Service NameOfMyService')}
```

(adapted from [aws docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-powershell.html))

You can easily loop through an array of Profile names like this:

```
$awsOrgProfiles = @('OrgAccount1', 'OrgAccount2', 'OrgAccountX');

$awsOrgProfiles | % {
   Send-SSMCommand -ProfileName $_ ...
}
```

(`$_` will contain one the ProfileName, rest of the command is the same as above)